# Time taken by 'rosmake roboearth'

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, roboearth, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were few issues during 'rosmake roboearth' for perception_pcl (ROS: Fuerte) due to which it failed earlier. I installed the patch and followed the workaround as suggested here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/64501/pcl-error-in-ros-fuerte/

And then issued 'rosmake roboearth' command but it's been making for the past 3 hours without prompting for any errors. What could be the issue ? Any suggestions please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65239/time-taken-by-%27rosmake-roboearth%27./) by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The process was waiting for failures in dependent packages to be rectified. Installed updated version of PCL and tried rosmake. It worked.

---

Originally posted by [Devasena Inupakutika](https://answers.ros.org/users/4122/devasena-inupakutika/) with karma: 320 on 2013-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0